# adding new column with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape google play apps , I want to add a new column "Google" with the value True/False if the app is available/unavailable

this is my csv file "apkmonk.csv"

```
Id,Genre,LastUpdated,Name,Package
0, Adventure,"Dec 16, 2021",Merge Mermaids-design home&create magic fish life. apk,com.xjoy.mermaid
1, Adventure,"Dec 10, 2021",Nob's World - Super Run Game apk,org.game69studio.nobworld
2, Adventure,"Dec 15, 2021",Fps Shooting Strike: Gun Games apk,com.mizo.fps.shooting.strike
3, Adventure,"Dec 12, 2021",Ostrich Air Jet Robot Car Game apk,com.cgs.us.police.flying.transform.robot.bike.game
```

my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('apkmonk.csv')

def googleplay(package):
        url=f"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={package}"
        html_content = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
        title= soup.title.text
        if "Not Found" in title:
            print("not found")
            return False
        else:
            print(" found")
            return True
            
for package in df["Package"]:

    if googleplay(package) is True:
        df["Google"] = "True"
    else: 
        df["Google"] = "False"      

    
df.to_csv("new.csv", sep=',')
```

Comment: What is your question? a.k.a. what does not work at the current code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df["Google"] = df["Package"].apply(googleplay)
```

If need strings `'True', 'False'` instead boolean:

```
df["Google"] = df["Package"].apply(googleplay).astype(str)
```

Comment: this is so smart it worked really well! thanks